# where to keep system.property in TestNG test case

Tags: java, selenium, automated-tests, testng, geckodriver

Where should I add the following statement
    `System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","//home//tuser//software//selenium//gecko_driver//geckodriver");`

so that my code does not produce an error

```
public class class1 {

public static String baseURL = "https://facebook.com/";
public WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

@Test(priority = 1)
public void login() throws InterruptedException {

    driver.get(baseURL);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("srikanth");
    driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("sri");
    driver.findElement(By.id("login_button")).click();
    Thread.sleep(30000);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used the answer provided by Jainish, but it didn't worked for me. For the same, I found out the following resolution:

```
    public class class1 {

    //public WebDriver object so that it can be used anywhere within class1
    public WebDriver driver; 

    //public WebDriverWait object so that it can be used anywhere within class1
    public WebDriverWait wait;

    @BeforeClass
    public void setup()
        {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\geckodriver.exe");
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,15); //explicit wait to increase performance
        }

    @Test()
    public void login() {

        driver.get("https://facebook.com/");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("username")));
        driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("srikanth");
        driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("sri");
        driver.findElement(By.id("login_button")).click();

        }
    }
```

I have modified the code written by Jainish. 
In the modified code, you can see that objects are declared with public scope outside any method, hence, allowing us to use this object anywhere within **class1**.

Also, there is no need to use static wait (which is Thread.sleep) and at implicit wait at the same time. Instead use Explicit wait to increase the script performance.

Hope, the above is useful. Please let me know if I am wrong anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

See the snippet below

```
public class class1 {
@Test(priority = 1)
public void login() throws InterruptedException {
    String baseURL = "https://facebook.com/";
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\Selenium Training\\Practice\\Firefox driver\\geckodriver.exe"); //Make sure to provide .exe extn
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get(baseURL);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys("srikanth");
    driver.findElement(By.id("pass")).sendKeys("sri");
    driver.findElement(By.id("u_0_n")).click();
    Thread.sleep(30000);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Again when next method will be used this is showing an error.have u used it with testNG framework?

Comment: What do you mean by next method used? Can you elaborate? Are you trying to use the driver in another test method?

Comment: in method 1 ,I declared system.property but when I used same drv driver in another test case(method) again I needed to declare system.property

Comment: Obviously! You need to create a base class with driver declaration and extend it to all your test classes!

Comment: Thanks , I will try

Comment: @VikasTiwari: Accept the answer if it resolved your question!

Comment: This won't resolve the problem as you will have to declare the webdriver object in each test case. Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class class1 {

@Test
public void setup() throws InterruptedException
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\geckodriver.exe");
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(25, TimeUnit.SECONDS);        
    }

@Test(dependsOnMethods = {"setup"})
public void login() throws InterruptedException {

    driver.get("https://facebook.com/");
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("srikanth");
    driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("sri");
    driver.findElement(By.id("login_button")).click();
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please Mark this answer as Accepted if it's resolved your issue. So it will help for other users as well. Thanks:)

Comment: This won't work as driver type "WebDriver" is not declared anywhere. Also, there is no need to use static and implicit wait both at the same time as it reduces the performance. Correct me if I am wrong.